# IE8 custom jQuery maxlength onpaste-script for textareas drops value

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, maxlength

I have the following jQuery script in use, which implements a maxLength behaviour for textareas.

Here's my code:

**code deleted** see fiddle instead: http://jsfiddle.net/G7mA7/2/

I am not searching for another script because this usally works fine, but only usally :-)

Now the real weired thing bout this.
Try my code in IE8 and hold ctrl + v to paste something in a textarea. As you can quickly see after reaching the maxLimit the whole text of the textarea is deleted! If you do it step by step everything works fine.

First I thought the next paste event starts before the other is finisched, but as far as I can see this is not the case.

So dudes.. why is this happening when I stay on paste, but does not happen when I do it step by step?

**update**
I've forked the fiddle from @thedixon so you can see the effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/G7mA7/

Just open it in IE8. Safe a string like "0123456789" into your clipboard, click into the textarea and stay on ctrl + v to paste.. as you can see the text disappears after reaching the limit.

**update** sorry, had to update the code, because the simple code did not even work in simplest case. It's now a bit complexer, but without the other elements the "step by step" pasting wont work.. but now see for yourself.

Comment: Why not use the jQuery methods to read and write values in the textarea instead? You are using jQuery anyway...

Comment: you're write.. i'll give it a try. But do you think this may solve my problem?

Comment: @Baszz because you don't need jQuery to do everything, and, by the way, jQuery uses those calls to do things

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: I know...but one of the reasons jQuery is here, is to solve a lot of cross browser issues. This could be one of them.

Comment: So I've tested it with jQuery read and write, but the effect is the same.

Comment: had to update my code because even the step by step thing did not work. now it's excatly the code I use in my application.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9FECn/2/ - Here's an example, works for me!

Comment: The same behaviour is there. I've forked your fiddle, so you can see it better: http://jsfiddle.net/G7mA7/ You may also see the update above